# Kubernetes replicaset creation using yaml file failed

Tags: kubernetes

When running command: **kubectl create -f rs.yaml** gives error

rs.yaml

```
kind: ReplicaSet
apiVersion: apps/v1
metadata:
  name: myrs
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: rsexample
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: rsexample
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: rscontainer
        image: aamirpinger/helloworld:latest
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
```

When running command:
**kubectl create -f rs.yaml** gives error

**error: error parsing rs.yaml: error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: line 13: found character that cannot start any token**

Comment: please add the yaml description

Comment: I add the yaml file

Comment: If you try to use `kubectl` commands with a PNG file as you've shown you'll get YAML parsing errors like that.  Can you replace the image with the text of the file you're using?

Comment: Yes I replace the image with text

Answer (score 1):

Its indentation issue, using tab instead of space(when replacing tab with space in line:13  error resolve)

Answer (score 1):

Indentation is wrong in your yaml. Here is an example which works. Since you have uploaded an image rather the actual yaml it's not possible to fix your yaml in an answer.

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: ReplicaSet
metadata:
  name: frontend
  labels:
    app: guestbook
    tier: frontend
spec:
  # modify replicas according to your case
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      tier: frontend
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        tier: frontend #Look here
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: php-redis
        image: gcr.io/google_samples/gb-frontend:v3
```

Comment: Yes its indentation issue. I used tab key in line 13 when replacing with space this error resolve